# Replacing multiple slashes with exception in regex

Tags: php, regex

There are quite a few questions on removing multiple slashes using regex in PHP. However, I have a special case I would like to exclude.

I have a full URL as my input: `http://localhost/path/to/whatever`

I have written to regex to convert backslashes to forward slashes, and then remove multiple consecutive slashes:

```
$cleaned = preg_replace('/(\\\+)|(\/+)/', "/", trim($input));
```

This works fine for the most part, however I need to be able to exclude the `://` case, otherwise using that expression will result in which is not the intended result:

```
http:/localhost/path/to/whatever
```

I have tried using `/(\\\+)|^[:](\/+)/`, but this doesn't seem to work.

How can I exclude the `://` case in my expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$cleaned = preg_replace('~(?<!https:|http:)[/\\\\]+~', "/", trim($input));
```

The subexpression inside the lookbehind can't use quantifiers, so the obvious approach - `(?<!https?:)` - won't work.  But it can be made up of two or more *fixed-length* alternatives with different lengths.   For example:

```
(?<!https:|http:)     # OK
```

Be aware that the alternation has to be at the *top level* of the lookbehind, so this won't work:

```
(?<!(https:|http:))   # error
```

Comment: This works perfectly and is quite simple as well :) Using `~` as the delimiter works, but I am finding that if I switch delimiters to `/` I get `Unknown modifier '/'` in some cases. Why is this the case? is there a special meaning for `/(` in regex?

Comment: The slashes (or tildes in my code) are the **[regex delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)**.  You can use almost any punctuation character for that, but the opening and closing delimiters have to match, and if that character appears in the regex it has to be escaped.  Otherwise, the compiler will think that's the closing delimiter, and it will treat the next character (if there is one) as a mode modifier (like `i` for case-insensitivity or `m` for multiline).  Hence the cryptic error message.

Comment: Thanks for your explaination :)

Answer (score 0):

There is something called "negative look behind" (also available in positive or look ahead)

http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-Regex.html

With this you could add an exception by something like

```
(?<=^https?:)
```

Then your expression will only match in places NOT preceded by "http:"

Comment: The `?` (or any quantifier) inside the lookbehind is a syntax error.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simply a negative look-behind for a colon, preceding two or more forward or backward slashes:

```
$cleaned = preg_replace('/(?<!:)(?:\\/|\\\\){2,}/', "/", trim($input));
```

Comment: This one seems to work perfectly. Could you explain the different pieces of this expression?

Comment: This doesn't replace a single backslash, as in `localhost\path`

Comment: `/(?<!:)/` means 'not preceded by a colon. `/(?:\\/|\\\\)/` means 'a slash or a backslash', made ugly by the number of escapes necessary to pass slash and backslash through. And `/{2,}/` means 'two or more times'. So the complete regex means 'two or more slashes or backslashes, not preceded by a colon. If you like my answer then an upvote, if not an acceptance, would be nice.

Comment: To fix the problem that Alan pointed out, change the regex to `'/(?<!:)(?:\\/|\\\\)+/`.

Comment: Just tried your solution again, and it doesn't seem to catch any forward slashes in regexbuddy.

Comment: You must remove the additional escapes if they are not needed for a particular environment. It is only PHP that requires such a mess of backslashes. I don't have regexbuddy and there is no demo available, but I imagine you want to use `(?<!:)(?:/|\\)+`.